# Bot Framework is calling constructor of object again between dialogs

Tags: c#, oop, dialog, botframework, chatbot

Hi all sorry this is my first time posting a question as I haven't been able to find a solution. I am making a chatbot in MS-Bot Framework and trying to pass the object 'Project' to another dialog:

```
return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(searchProject2), new Project(new string[]{"ixnID"}, new string[]{"1"}), cancellationToken);
```

However, when I do this in the next dialog, after typing in a message into a TextPrompt the bot immediately crashes and returns a NullReferenceException error:

```
     [OnTurnError] unhandled error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ixnChatbot.Project..ctor(String[] rawFields, String[] values) in C:\Users\a\ixnChatbot\Models\Project.cs:li
ne 24
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 cr
eator, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonPro
perty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract,
JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) .............
```

After debugging I discovered that the constructor is being called twice, even though after passing Project into the new dialog it isn't accessed by any of my code. Here is the constructor and the variables in the class it uses:

```
protected readonly int ixnID;
private Dictionary<string, int> fields = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private string[] values;

protected string fieldGetterQueryWholeTable
    = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name in('IXN_database_entries')";
protected string searchQuery;

public Project(string[] rawFields, string[] values)
{
    this.values = values;

    for (int i = 0; i < rawFields.Length; i++)
    {
        fields.Add(rawFields[i], i);
    }

    ixnID = Int32.Parse(values[fields["ixnID"]]);
    searchQuery =
        "SELECT * FROM IXN_database_entries i WHERE i.ixnID = " + ixnID;
}
```

Here is the waterfall step it is being used in. As you can see I haven't touched the object being passed in:

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> oneAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    var promptOptions = new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("What would you like to know about this project?") };
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), promptOptions, cancellationToken);
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> twoAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(stepContext.Result.ToString());
    return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(InitialDialogId, null, cancellationToken);
}
```

The error occurs between these two waterfall steps. I was able to debug and find that for some reason, the bot was re-calling the constructor in the Project class, but on the second time it is called the list 'rawField' passed in as a parameter is null and this is why it throws this NullReference error.

My question is, how do I stop the framework from doing this? I do not understand why passing in an object causes this kind of error and it doesn't appear to occur when using primitive types like strings. I have searched for a while and haven't found any questions similar to this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution (whoops) just in case anyone ever gets this issue.

I just added an empty constructor to the Project class so that when it was called, there was no null error on its parameters.

```
public Project()
    {

    }
```

This also worked:

```
[JsonConstructor]
private Project()
{

}
```